# argparse argument in global namespace will override other file's arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

This is a behavior i notice during autoscript dev.
Now I have two files name `main.py` and `test.py`,
main.py code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
import os
import sys
import time
from pathlib import Path
import pytest
import configparser as cpaser

test_config = {}

def config_test_env():
    global test_config
    case_path = Path(base_dir, 'testcase')
    now = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
    test_reports_address = Path(base_dir, 'report')
    test_log_address = Path(base_dir, 'log')
    if not test_reports_address.exists():
        os.mkdir(test_reports_address)
    if not test_log_address.exists():
        os.mkdir(test_log_address)
    filepath = Path(test_reports_address, now + "_report.html")
    test_config['filepath'] = str(filepath)
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='main.py - excute testcases')
    parser.add_argument('-H', '-Host', dest='host', help='host url', default='http://192.168.1.169')
    parser.add_argument('-t', dest='testcase_path', help='testcase path', type=str, default=case_path)
    parser.add_argument('-r', dest='test_report_path', help='testreport path', default=filepath)
    parser.add_argument('-m', help='run specific mark type testcase',
                        choices=['smoke_test', 'ui_test', 'api_test', 'demonstration'])
    parser.add_argument('--driver', help='specific webdriver to perform UI test', default='chrome')
    parser.add_argument('-s', help='print testcase execute result on screen', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-c', help='enable code coverage check', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-cr', '-check_response_time', help='check API reponse time', dest='ct', action='store_true',
                        default=False)
    parser.add_argument('-dc', '-delete_case', dest='delete_case_flag',
                        help='whether delete case after testcase finish',
                        action='store_true', default=False)
    parser.add_argument('-mt', '-max_response_time', dest='mt', help='api max response time set', default=30, type=int)
    parser.add_argument('-sr', '-send_report', dest='send_report', help='whether send report after test excute',
                        action='store_true', default=False)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    host = str(args.host)
    test_config['host'] = host
    ct_flag = args.ct
    csv_file_path = str(Path(base_dir, host.split('//')[1] + '_api_response_time.csv'))
    test_config['csv_file_path'] = csv_file_path
    test_config['ct_flag'] = ct_flag
    mt = args.mt
    test_config['mt'] = mt
    if ct_flag:
        create_csv_file(csv_file_path)
    dc_flag = args.delete_case_flag
    test_config['dc_flag'] = dc_flag
    test_config['send_report'] = args.send_report
    pytest_args = [
        '-v',
        str(args.testcase_path),
        '--html=' + str(args.test_report_path),
        '--self-contained-html',
        '--driver', str(args.driver)
    ]
    test_config['pytest_args'] = pytest_args


config_test_env()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # pytest main
    pass
```

test.py code:

```
from main import test_config

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # pytest main
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='store case using thread')
    parser.add_argument('-t', '-total', dest='total_case', help='total_case number', type=int, default=100)
    parser.add_argument('-r', dest='per_round', help='case number per round, thread number', type=int, default=100)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    pass
```

I want `main.py` to set some global variable so I place method `config_test_env` in global namespace and update global `test_confg` so can be import by other file.
But when I execute `python3 test.py -h`, the ouput is:

```
usage: test2.py [-h] [-H HOST] [-t TESTCASE_PATH] [-r TEST_REPORT_PATH] [-m {smoke_test,ui_test,api_test,demonstration}] [--driver DRIVER] [-s] [-c] [-cr] [-dc] [-mt MT] [-sr]

main.py - excute testcases

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -H HOST, -Host HOST   host url
  -t TESTCASE_PATH      testcase path
  -r TEST_REPORT_PATH   testreport path
  -m {smoke_test,ui_test,api_test,demonstration}
                        run specific mark type testcase
  --driver DRIVER       specific webdriver to perform UI test
  -s                    print testcase execute result on screen
  -c                    enable code coverage check
  -cr, -check_response_time
                        check API reponse time
  -dc, -delete_case     whether delete case after testcase finish
  -mt MT, -max_response_time MT
                        api max response time set
  -sr, -send_report     whether send report after test excute
```

Apparently the `test.py` arguments seemed be ovrride by the `main.py`, so i am wondering the solution that can import global varible from `main.py` but also don't override argument

Comment: Because of its location, `config_test_env()` is run when importing `main`.  The first parser to be called catches the `-h`, prints its help, and does a system exit.  The `test.py` parser is never run.  If you give other commandline values, both parsers will run, and expect compatible arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `from main import test_config` the whole `main` module is being executed.

Because the call to `config_test_env()` is not protected by `if __name__ == '__main__':`, it is being called as part of the import.

Inside this call you define a `parser` and then call `args = parser.parse_args()`. Because you ran with `-h`, the call to `parse_args` prints the help message (of `main`) and exits the program.

---

As to solving this, it's hard to say as I don't fully understand what you're doing. Either put the `config_test_env()` under `if __name__ == '__main__':`, or at least just the `parser` creation should be only executed when the file is the main one.

Comment: I want `test_confg` can be import and use by other files, if I put `config_test_env()` into `if __name__ == '__main__':` ,the `test_config` is {} and won't be initialize by arguments,

Comment: Ok but then again if you do it like that it will always parse the arguments from within `main` and never add the other arguments. You have both `-t` and `-r` in both parsers. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Well, the `-t` and `-r` parsers can work, but if i run `python3 test.py -h` it always print the `main.py`'s argument help info, not `test.py`. So i want to to know if there is a better way to their argument help info separately but also can import global variable from `main.py`

Comment: Again, this is not as simple as you put it and might require a different design to your program. I will ask again, assuming it all worked fine, when you run `test.py` what would you expect the parser to look like? You have both `-t` and `-r` in `test.py` and `main.py`. How will that reflect to the parser when running `test`?

Comment: Currently both arguments can be execute smoothly on their `__man__` phase, I think i need to re-design the variable share way, better close it.